# Use HTML5 chart via JasperReports API

Tags: java, highcharts, jasper-reports

I have created report dynamically via *JasperReports API* and I am using some charts objects.
 Report is created on server and then send to client in pdf format. Is it possible to use highcharts components on server and add it to report? I tried *iReport Professional Edition*, and it does include *HTML5*, can I use the same components via API? Is there any jar/include that I need to add to my project?

Comment: You can use one of highcharts wrapper, prepared by third party developers: http://www.highcharts.com/download

Comment: Thanks Sebastian, i will check this option. But i am looking for some combination between jasper API and high-charts in order to use use only query and not set chart/report data manually.